# Type a method that returns a object with properties from this?

Tags: typescript

How would I type this method where this.make is a function

```
abstract class Example{
  abstract from: string;
  abstract to: string;
  make (): string {
    return 'hi';
  }
  methods () {
    return ({
      from: {
        [this.from]: {
          to: {
            [this.to]: this.make,
          },
        },
      },
    });
  }
}
```

```
class Move extends Example {
  from = 'alpha';
  to = 'beta';
}

const x = (new Move()).methods().from;
```

[image]

Comment: I believe this should work. Are you getting an error? If so please share.

Comment: I added a image, I'd like these strings to have the value.

Comment: I just ran your scripts and nothing fails. I guess your question is still unclear to me.

Comment: Never mind I understand now. Answer will follow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using polymorphic `this` in the return type annotation of the function. You will need to use a type assertion to get the implementation to work but the derived classes will be typed as expected.

Also the fields in the derived classes will either need to be typed explicitly as the string literal types or declared as readonly to make the compiler not widen the type to `string`:

```
type MethodResult<TFrom extends string, TTo extends string> = {
    from: Record<TFrom, {
        to: Record<TTo, string>
    }>
}
abstract class Example{
  abstract from: string;
  abstract to: string;
  make (): string {
    return 'hi';
  }
  methods () : MethodResult<this['from'],this['to']> {
    return ({
      from: {
        [this.from]: {
          to: {
            [this.to]: this.make,
          },
        },
      },
    }) as any;
  }
}
class Move extends Example {
  readonly from = 'alpha';
  readonly to = 'beta';
}

const x = (new Move()).methods().from.alpha.to.beta;
```

Answer (score 0):

Typescript is a compile-time language. It's therefore generally not possible to do run-time typing, and the state of `this` is fundamentally a runtime state.

There is certainly a possibility for a single abstract type to return diffent things depending on implementation, but this has to be done at compile time.

So if you're not familiar with this, the general tool for this is Generics.

Here's an example of this, that doesn't *exactly* do what you want, but gives you something that somewhat close to this.

```
type MoveAbstract = {
  from: {
     [s:string]: {
       to: {
         [s: string]: () => string
       }
     }
  }
}

abstract class Example<T extends MoveAbstract> {
  abstract from: string;
  abstract to: string;
  make (): string {
    return 'hi';
  }
}

type MakeMove = {
  from: {
     alpha: {
       to: {
         beta: () => string
       }
     }
  }
}

class Move extends Example<MakeMove> {
  from = 'alpha';
  to = 'beta';
  methods (): MakeMove {
    return ({
      from: {
        alpha: {
          to: {
            beta: this.make,
          },
        },
      },
    });
  }

}

const x = (new Move()).methods().from;
```

I realize this is not *exactly* what you're looking for, and probably has more repetition than you'd like, but from the perspective of something that is a consumer of the `Example` abstract class, you can mostly make this work.

Maybe it's possible to optimize further, but I'm not sure!